# Export maps with different text using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I am new in ArcPy. i want to export month wise map with different title using ArcPy. Maps are exporting correctly but the title remains "January 2018". I used the following code. What is wrong?

```
import arcpy

mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")

lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"*2018")

month=["January 2018","February 2018","March 2018","April 2018","May 2018","June 2018"]

elm=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Date")

for el in elm:

  for ly in lyr:
    ly.visible= True
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    el.text=month[0]
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd,"C:/HILAL/Pamba GW Data/delete/Map/"+ly.name)
    ly.visible= False
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: el.text=month[0] is always january (the first element in month list).you should loop over months.

Comment: Remember that the software will only do what you tell it to do, not what you want it to do. `el.text=month[0]` needs to change. You haven't attempted to change the zero radix.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looping through `elm` if you want to change only one element which corresponds to the title? I assume `elm` is a list with only one element. Keeping this into account, you can remove your first `for` loop and you can change your current line for the following:

```
elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT","Date")[0]
```

Furthermore, as @umbe1987 and @Vince pointed out, you are replacing the title everytime for the first element in `month` (*i.e* `"January 2018"`). Assuming `lyr` and `month` have the same number of elements (one layer for each month), you can use the `enumerate` function to loop through your layers and get a integer every loop corresponding to the month.

```
for i, ly in enumerate(lyr):
    ly.visible = True
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    elm.text = month[i]  # notice that el changed to elm
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, "C:/HILAL/Pamba GW Data/delete/Map/" + ly.name)
    ly.visible = False
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```